# How to show all data for specific user ID?

Tags: php, mysql

I have table called `users_points` in MySQL:

[image]

I tried to show all data that related to user `id=2`

[image]

But I couldn't find the best `SELECT` for this job.

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM users where id=2
```

But it just give me the first row in the table, not all rows.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users where id=2`?

Comment: I did this, but it just give me the first row in the table.

Comment: then fix your php code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is fine with your query,
 
You should search for other reasons why it doesn't output wanted information,
 if you are using PHP to output information use `while` cycle!

For example (if you output data with PHP):

```
<?php 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users where id=2";
    if($result = $mysqli->query($query)){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '#'.$row['id'].' - '$row['name'].' - '.$row['points'].' - '.$row['date'].'<br />';
        }
    }
?>
```